# Excel data scaling

Tags: excel

I have a small dataset in Excel, I want to make a spider plot with excel, but one data is extremely larger than others, which result to a spider plot with only one straight line in the graph, how can i normalize those data or re-scale the spider plot in excel to make all the others also be shown in the graph?

T=2*10^-6
2.24E+09

V=10^6
0.0024

U=10
1.38E+03

WeightThresholdToBeExtracted=0.9
8.72E+04

Sigma_v=5
9.93E+02

Sigma_r=10
1.14E+03

Prob_detection=0.7
1.59E+05

Prob_survival=0.7
3.86E+03

[the chart figure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfUej.png)

Comment: Have you tried getting logarithms of your values, then making a plot with those? it should help with the scaling problem, though there may be drawbacks to this.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks for your reply, i tried with logarithms, the result was good, thanks.